# How to add Customer Address Attribute to order API rest/V1/orders - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api, custom-attributes

I want to add Custom Address Attribute field in order api,

The field data is saved in sales_order_address table, but it dosen't show in order api

Anyone have idea how to add it to order api?

Answer (score 0):

The custom field must be added as an extension attribute for `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface`.

This will make it visible (if populated) inside the 'billing_address -> extension_attributes' and/ or 'extension_attributes -> shipping_assignments -> shipping -> address -> extension_attributes' areas of the response of the `/rest/V1/orders/{id}` endpoint.

Comment: Hi @diana-botean I have added the field in the extension attribute, but its not working.

Comment: ok.. that's strange.

Comment: Can you check this? https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html#ext-aut i am not sure which authentication type are you using, maybe you need to change permissions or something.

Comment: i couldn't found anything for orders, currently, I have defined the attribute using Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderAddressInterface, but it's not working.

Comment: i still think this is a permission's issue check this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication.html#accessible-resources and also in `vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/webapi.xml` the "/V1/orders/:id" clearly states that you need admin or integration permissions to see the data. if you are using an admin user token then i would double check that the admin has permissions over the order view actions.

Answer (score 0):

Create extension_attribute to add customer address to your order

See how to add at: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-extension-attributes-to-entity-magento-2.html